# Display tag not working on Weblogic 9.2 but works fine on Weblogic 11g

Tags: struts2, displaytag, weblogic11g, weblogic9.x

I have a display Table written as

```
 <display:table name="${someList}" class="displayTagTable" 
             uid="service" requestURI="" defaultsort="2">
```

This implementation works fine when deployed on Weblogic 11g. However, if deployed on Weblogic 9.2, the table does not show anything. I do not any errors either.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you (a) checked your JS console for errors, and (b) checked you server logs (with devMode=true and logging at DEBUG)?

Comment: IF the library is the same, AND the project too, THEN it must be a problem of the application server. Probably, taglib loaded twice due to different jars included in ear e/o present on server, or somehitng like that... i used Display Tag on Oracle 9 without problems

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I did solve this issue by completely removing EL expression. For some reason EL expression doesn't work in displayTag if deployed in Weblogic 9.2

Comment: Please go ahead and add an answer to your question. It might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this issue by completely removing EL expression. For some reason EL expression doesn't work in displayTag if deployed in Weblogic 9.2